# How to view all data master table of specific column from another table of column where relationship in access database using vb.net 2019

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007, visual-studio-2019

Here is my problem in SQL query, result has been successful to load data in datagrid like SL_No (2,4,5) but some data are missing from table `Pairing` like (1,2,3,4,5,6) where relationship table data is not available like (1,3,6) in `Receipt` table.

```
Private Sub BtnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click

    Dim Sql as String = "Select Pairing.Ledger_Index, Pairing.Fr_Customer_no, Pairing.Fr_Customer_nm, Receipt.Dt_Entry, Receipt.Price from Pairing INNER JOIN Receipt ON Pairing.Fr_Customer_no = Receipt.Sub_No WHERE (((Pairing.Ledger_Address)='" & cmbList.Text & "'))""

    If RdoLedger.Checked=True Then
       DatagridView_Load("sql",DatagridView1)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function DatagridView_Load(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal Model As DataGridView)
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
        Model.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        If IsDBNull(dt) = False Then
            Model.DataSource = (dt)
            con.Close()
        Else
            Model.DataSource = Nothing
            con.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank You No Body reply Me, Because I will not understand this questions answer. This is some simple answer. here i was wanted all record of 1st table.
 so my query was should be =
**from Pairing INNER JOIN Receipt** changed to **from Pairing *left* JOIN Receipt**
its get my result successfully

Comment: You can accept your own answer. You won't get points but it will be helpful for future readers.